# JQuery - Preserve string when injecting elements into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically add elements to the DOM to populate a list of search results. The code looks like

```
for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
    console.log(temp[i].CATEGORY);
    console.log(temp[i].SUBCATEGORY);
    table = table + '<tr class="search-tr"><td class="search-td"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick=window.parent.iframeLink("content-iframe","search-ui.cfm","'+temp[i].CATEGORY+'","d") target="content-window"><span class="subcat">'+temp[i].SUBCATEGORY+'</span><span class="cat"> in '+temp[i].CATEGORY+'</span></a></td></tr>';
}
```

When I inspect the element that through the browser, the string "temp[i].CATEGORY" which is injected is supposed to be 'Server Settings'. Instead, it is injected as 'Server" Settings' which is causing everything to break.

I have done a lot of searching but I'm unable to find any references to this issue.

Comment: what is in temp.category and temp.subcategory

Comment: You have a `onClick` attribute value that is not in quotes.
Try `onClick=\'window.parent.iframeLink("content-iframe","search-ui.cfm","'+temp[i].CATEGORY+'","d")\'`

Comment: How do you generate `temp[i].CATEGORY` value?

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran just strings

Comment: He's asking what do the console logs print out

Comment: @Titus Strangely that worked. Could you explain how some functions can be called without quotes? And also write an answer so that it can be marked as correct.

Comment: @Alexander They are generated from the server

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran console.log prints 'Server Settings' only

Comment: On one line? Or separate lines?

Comment: @Taplar On one line. Putting the entire function call within quotes works. As suggestd by Titus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a onClick attribute value that is not in quotes. Try `onClick=\'window.parent.iframeLink("content-iframe","search-‌​ui.cfm","'+temp[i].C‌​ATEGORY+'","d")\'`

In HTML a attribute's value needs to be quoted if it contains spaces or quotes. Given that in this case the value contains double quotes you can use single quotes to encapsulate it.

Also, since you're constructing the string using single quotes you'll need to escape the single quotes that are used to encapsulate the attribute's value

Comment: Marking it as the correct answer as it was first answered in the comments under the question.